# Common Library not provided on TIZEN samples

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

on Both tutorials:
http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/tut00062/index

http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/tut00055/index

Are references to a folder named Common/API and it is supposed to be provided, but it is not.

Do someone knows where to download them?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out myself a long time ago, but I forgot to answer it. That library were provided just in old versions. Even if you find them  probably wouldn´t be comnpatible.
There is no REAL solution, the tutorials should be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you refer to this in the code:

```
<!-- Common widget API -->
    <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/webapi/1.0/webapis.js"></script>
```

These are part of the SSSP API and I've seen them on SSSP3 displays. Basically if you run a Web Application on an SSSP3 ( or 2 ) display you use these to control the display API. The objects already exist when you start an application on the display (possibly in the SDK as well, this I do not know) and you retrieve them. For example Common/API/TVKeyValue.js provides an interface for the remote control of the TV. Afaik under the hood there is a C++ wrapper, as the native calls of the display are happening via C++.

EDIT:

Also I forgot to mention - the API you are having trouble with is pre-TIZEN. This Common/API is SSSP3, TIZEN arrived with SSSP4. This is what the SSSP4 includes look like:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='$B2BAPIS/b2bapis/b2bapis.js'></script>
```